# Maximum attained on extreme points of the ball in $\mathcal{L}(^2\ell^3_\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lp-spaces

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathcal{L}(^2\ell^3_\infty)$ (over $\Bbb R$), $\text{ext}B$ be the set of its extreme points and $f\in\mathcal{L}(^2\ell^3_\infty)^*$. How can I show that $$\|f\|=\sup_{x\in \text{ext}B}|f(x)|.$$

It seems that we can't use the Krein-Milman Theorem because $B$ is not compact. Do you know another approach?

Comment: who is $\mathcal{L}(^2 l^3_\infty)?$ I think this is a typo. I answered anyways a general question. Maybe it helps you

Comment: @Magnusseen $\mathcal{L}(^2\ell^2_\infty)=\{T:\ell_\infty^2\times\ell_\infty^2\to\Bbb R~|~T~\text{linear}\}$. I don't know if there is a typo or a misunderstanding. In another paper I am reading the author say "let $n\geq2$ and $l_\infty^n:=\Bbb R^n$ with the sup norm". If this is a different notation for $\Bbb R^n$, my problem is solved (actually there was no problem at all). But I don't understand why they use this notation. For me, $\ell_\infty=\{x=(x_j)\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}~|~\sup|x_j|<\infty\}$ and $\ell_\infty^2=\ell_\infty\times\ell_\infty$. Do you know why they put $l_\infty^n:=\Bbb R^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normed space is reflexive iff $B$ is weakly compact. Apply now [Bauer's Maximum Theorem](https://books.google.de/books?id=oL9ncMnFQFgC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=bauer%27s%20maximum%20theorem&source=bl&ots=GuCTV1vfMs&sig=0CYGUHJYKWXU3SR38PT6GypSLLo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_-bSnzvDVAhXKVhoKHfiKB_A4ChDoAQgsMAI#v=onepage&q=bauer's%20maximum%20theorem&f=false) with $|f|,$ $B,$ and considering the weak topology.

I haven't shown that your space is reflexive, so...

Comment: The link is not available anymore

Comment: I've noticed that there is a typo in the link. Now can access the pdf.

Comment: @Filburt I edited, try now.